# Merge dataframes on column with count of unique IDs

Tags: python, pandas, transform, combinations

I have 4 dataframes:

```
symptoms = pd.DataFrame(columns=['subject', 'name', 'type'])
AA_alleles = pd.DataFrame(columns=['subject', 'chrom', 'pos', 'bp', 'SNPid'])
Aa_alleles = pd.DataFrame(columns=['subject', 'chrom', 'pos', 'bp', 'SNPid'])
aa_alleles = pd.DataFrame(columns=['subject', 'chrom', 'pos', 'bp', 'SNPid'])
```

'subject' in all dataframes contains a unique subject ID.  I want to find the combinations of all symptoms and alleles, with a count of subjects per combinations, plus a column for the zygosity (the AA, Aa or aa for each df name).  E.g the results I'm looking for is:

```
['symptom_name', 'symptom_type', 'zygosity', 'chrom', 'pos', 'bp', 'SNPid', 'subject_count']
```

What's the best way to do this transformation? For reference, this is to create the data ready for a Freeman-Halton test.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, are all ```subject``` ids in ```**_alleles``` subsets of the ids in ```symptoms```?

Comment: They will be, although I'm considering excluding aa_alleles due to the length of queries, so these counts will consist of total subjects - the other two for the analysis.  So far, I've done **_alleles['zygosity'] = ** and am just about to do an inner merge on subject for each **_alleles... I'm guessing that's pretty much it, then i need to work out how to reduce to frequencies.  There are 8m+ rows in Aa_alleles and would be way more in aa_allales, so I'm not sure if there would be a more efficient method than purely appending and then reducing.

Answer (score 1):

I think I worked this out:

```
AA_alleles['zygosity'] = 'AA'
Aa_alleles['zygosity'] = 'Aa'
aa_alleles['zygosity'] = 'aa'
df = symptoms.merge(AA_alleles, on='subject')
df2 = symptoms.merge(Aa_alleles, on='subject')
df3 = symptoms.merge(aa_alleles, on='subject')
total = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
total = total.append(df3, ignore_index=True)
count = total.groupby(['chrom','pos','bp','SNPid','zygosity','name','type']).count()
```

Seems to do the trick:

```
Chromosome_X    2724760     T   rs55842969;rs111382948  Aa  Albumin     high    1
                                                                BMI     high    1
                                                                FEV1    high    1
                                                                        low     1
                                                                FVC     high    1
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
Chromosome_9    141016320   A   rs41290003  Aa  Trunkal Fat Mass    high    1
                                                            Urea    high    1
                                                            VLDL    high    1
                                                            WHR     high    2
                                                            Weight  high    1
```